# How to narrow down an union type with JSDoc for VSCode?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm calling a method with returns a union type. But as the caller, I know the actual type. Is there a way to tell VSCode the actual type?

For example:

```js
let selectedEntry = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
let value = parseInt(selectedEntry);
```

The right hand side of the first assignment is of type `string | number | string[]`, so `selectedEntry` is of type `string | number | string[]`, too. Therefore, `parseInt(selectedEntry)` leads to the following warning:

*Argument of type 'string | number | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. ts(2345)*

In this case, I know that `val()` returns a `string`. But adding a JSDoc comment `/** @type string */` belongs to the lhs of the assignment, leading to the same warning, just a line before. So how can I specify the actual type returned by `val()`?

Answer (score 1):

(Caveat, I don't know anything about JQuery, but in JS ...)

You can do this in a couple of places:

```js
const selectedEntry = /** @type {string} */ (whatever.find("option:selected").val());
```

or:

```js
const value = parseInt(/** @type {string} */ (selectedEntry));
```

Note: The 'extra' round brackets are compulsory, in either case.